# Spring @RestController double @RequestBody json input

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have implemented the following classes:

```
public class classA {
    String fieldA;
}

public class classB {
    String fieldB;
}
```

Then i am using a rest controller having objects of these classes as input:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(value="/resource")
    public void foo(@RequestBody objA, @RequestBody objB){
        //do stuff
    } 
}
```

When i invoke the API using the following input:

```
{
    "objA" : {
        "fieldA" : "valueA"
    },
    "objB" : {
        "fieldB" : "valueB"
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public void com.classA
```

Am i missing something on the JSON input?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. There’s only one request body, so, you can’t have two declared in your method. You need a “container” of sort for the classes A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to have multiple @RequestBody. For that usecase you need to write a Wrapperclass:

```
public class ClassAB {
    ClassB classB;
    ClassA classA;
}
```

and then use it in the RestController:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(value="/resource")
    public void foo(@RequestBody ClassAB ab){
        // ab.classB
        // ab.classA
        // do stuff
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass more than one request body, you need to pass an Array of objects or have an outer object containing the two objects, or you could use a map, a JSONObject ecc.

There are many ways to do this depending on your use case.